# Valid Error Messages to display in Python

Tags: python

I have the below code in python for validating the phone numbers.
Right now, this program returns True or False.
Expecting error msgs when the result is False, something like:

1. Country code is wrong
2. The phone format for passed country is wrong.
3. Valid format for the given country is like this??

### Can some one help me with changes to the below code?

```
import phonenumbers


def is_valid(number,country):

    try:
        pn = phonenumbers.parse(number,country)
        if phonenumbers.is_possible_number(pn) and phonenumbers.is_valid_number(pn):
            return True
    except:
            return False
    return False

def validNumber(phone_number,country):

    try: 
        parsed = phonenumbers.format_number(phonenumbers.parse(phone_number,country),
                                            phonenumbers.PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL)
    except:
        parsed = str(None)
        print(parsed)
    return parsed

def main():
    while True:
        phone_number=input('Enter your telephone number: ')
        country=input('Enter your country: ')

        phone_number = phone_number.replace('+', '', 1)
    
        parsed = validNumber(phone_number,country)
        valid_value = is_valid(parsed,country)
        
        if valid_value:
            print('{} is a valid entry.'.format(phone_number))
            break
        else:
            print('{} is a not valid entry, please try again.'.format(phone_number))
main()
```

Comment: But what's the problem?

Comment: You have to try and then post the problems. Anyway, In your case, you have to catch the exception and in your phonenumbers script, if validation fails raise a custom exception like `Country code is wrong`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can print error messages inside except block in every validating function.
For example,

```
error_msg = "The phone format for passed country is wrong" 
def is_valid(number,country):
    try:
        pn = phonenumbers.parse(number,country)
        if phonenumbers.is_possible_number(pn) and phonenumbers.is_valid_number(pn):
            return True
    except phonenumbers.NumberParseException as e:
        print(e, error_msg)
    return False
```

Check this link for more info: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/104093/phonenumbers.NumberParseException

Comment: Ok, I got that...how to validate only country using Phonenumbers library?

Comment: @Samsul Islam, I tried your suggestion but the error_msg is not printing in the output. can you suggest here?

Comment: Use "raise" statement instead of print in the except block